# Main difference between Yahalom and Needham-Schroeder key exchange protocols

Tags: cryptography, protocols, key-exchange, asymmetric

I am just wondering what is the main difference between the [Yahalom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahalom_%28protocol%29) and [Needham-Schroeder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needham-Schroeder) key exchange protocols?  Which protocol uses less computational power?

Comment: I strongly suggest you shift this question to http://crypto.stackexchange.com/, it seems this is more appropriate there.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a table which can be useful. From the number of encryption and decryption operations, decide for yourself which one is computationally expensive from a client and key server perspective. A, B are clients and S is the key server.

[image: Number of operations]